# How do I use sp.if_ and sp.for_ control statements in pure Python?

Tags: smartpy

I'm following this: https://tezos.b9lab.com/smartpy/language guide, but it's written for the SmartPy online IDE, I'm trying to do this all in my local dev environment.

PyCharm IDE gives me an "An illegal target for a variable annotation" error when I use the `sp.for_`. Can anyone help me understand what am I doing wrong?

```
import smartpy as sp

class Summarise(sp.Contract):
    def __init__(self):
        self.init(storage=0)

    @sp.entry_point(name='sum')
    def sum(self, params):
        sp.for_ i in sp.range(1, params+1):
            pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. The desugared version is

```
with sp.for_("x", params) as x:
    self.data.result += x
```

https://smartpy.io/docs/general/control_statements

So the translation for this example is:

```
with sp.for_("i", sp.range(1, params+1)) as i:
    self.data.storage += i
```